# Taylor series analytic at $z = z_0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

There's something here I don't quite understand. It says that the sum of the first series (the power series) is analytic. What does that mean? I know that a function is analytic at a point if it has a derivative at that point. But say the function is a geometric series:

$$\frac{1}{1-z}$$

How can this be analytic at $z_0 = 1$?

What am I misunderstanding? Am I misunderstanding the difference between a function being analytic and a series being analytic?

Comment: If you're considering the geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n$, this definitely converges for $|z|<1$, and its sum is $\frac{1}{1-z}$. But in this case the $z_0$ is $0$, not $1$. So, I'm not sure what you're confused about.

Comment: It continues "as we know from the last section". If you haven't read that section, you may want to do so. If there's something more specific in there you didn't understand, you should ask that.

Comment: How can a series be analytic at a point where the function is undefined? @peek-a-boo Oh wait... I think I was confused. Is the z_0 not 1? It's 0?

Comment: Yes the $z_0$ for the series I wrote down is $0$ because $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}1\cdot(z-0)^n$; i.e we're expanding about the point $0$.

Comment: The "first series" is not the entire function. It refers to just the $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z - z_0)^n$$part. This is defined for every $z$ such that $|z-z_0| < R$, including $z_0$. It is the *second* series that is not defined at $z_0$.

Comment: ah I see @peek-a-boo and so that geometric series is analytic around $z = z_0$. Well what about when $z = 1$. I guess that doesn't matter since it's outside of the radius of convergence right?

Comment: The series does not converge when $z=1$; indeed the series becomes $1+1+1+1+1\dots$.

Comment: So that's why the fact that $\frac{1}{1-z}$ is undefined at z=1 is irrelevant.. .it's outside the radius of convergence right?